# Error with Jquery UI Dialog in Ie7 / Ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

have abit of a problem with Jquery UI dialog. I set it to modal:true, and so when i initialize the dialog, i do see the grey overlay. However, the dialog itself simply does not appear. This is the strange part (perhaps): when I put settings to autoOpen: true, the dialog appears fine, it simply does not appear again when i click. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();    
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

jQuery('#loginforms').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 230,
        width: 330,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() { jQuery(this).dialog('close'); },
            "Log in": function() { jQuery('#login').submit(); }
        }
 });

jQuery('#loginbutton li a').click(function(){
                jQuery('#loginforms').dialog('open');
                return false;
                                       });


 });

</script>
```

...

```
   <div id="loginforms" style="overflow-x:hidden;">

  <form method="post" action="summary.html" class="forms" id="login">

    <h2 style="font-size:16px; text-align:left;">Please login to your account: </h2><br />

    <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input value="" class="required" id="name" name="name" />

             <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input value="" class="required" id="password" name="password" type="password" />

</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd just post since i figured out the problem. It turns out that it was a incompatibility between curvycorners.js and jquery-UI (in particular, dialog). Sorry for not reflecting that in my question, it never occurred to me that the problem could be that. Just posting here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: Did you find the particular incompatibility?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not executing the Dialog.show, I think the problem is on the selector for the Anchor (link)
Check out the wrapped set returned when you are binding the Click.

```
jQuery('#loginbutton li a').click(function(){
```

does that selector retrieves you something?, cause I don't see it on your code example :S

hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks, yes it retrieves something, i just didn't include it. As mentioned, when I click it, the grey overlay appears, it's just that the dialog does not appear.